# Why is this recursive DFS so much faster than the algorithm using stack?

Tags: c++, complexity-theory, depth-first-search

I am doing a project with DFS/BFS algorithms. I wrote these three kinds of algorithms:
The recursive one:

```
void explore(int i)
{
    if (!v[i].visited)
    {
        v[i].visited = true;
    
        int n = adj[i].size();
        if (!adj[i].empty())
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                int w = adj[i][j];//acutal index in the vector
                explore(w);
            }
        
        }
        else {
        
            return;
        }//if the vertice is sink, return the upper level 
    }


    else {
        return;
    } //if visited, return immediately
}
void dfsRecursive() //the naive implementation of directed dfs
{

    int n = adj.size();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        v[i].visited = false;
    }
    for (int w = 0; w < n; w++) {
        if (!v[w].visited) {
            explore(w);
            
        }
    }

}
```

Using stack:

```
void dfsStack() {
    //using naive c++ stl stack
    size_t n = adj.size();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        v[i].visited = false;
    }
    stack<vertice> S;
    for (size_t k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        if (v[k].visited) { continue; }
        else
            v[k].visited = true;//start point v[0]
        S.push(v[k]);
        while (!S.empty())
        {
            vertice u = S.top();
            S.pop();//these two steps represent the operation pop
            size_t m = adj[u.index].size();
            int  index = -1;
            for (size_t j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                size_t i = adj[u.index][j];
                if (!v[i].visited)
                {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (index != -1)
            {
                S.push(u);
                v[index].visited = true;
                S.push(v[index]);
            }
        }
    }


    //S.~stack<vertice>();//release memory
}
```

And deque, basically replace all stack as deque:

```
void dfsDeque() {
    size_t n = adj.size();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        v[i].visited = false;
    }
    deque<vertice> D;
    for (size_t k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        if (v[k].visited) { continue; }
        else
            v[k].visited = true;//start point v[0]
        D.push_front(v[k]);
        while (!D.empty())
        {
            vertice u = D.front();
            D.pop_front();
            size_t m = adj[u.index].size();
            int index = -1;
            for (size_t j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                size_t i = adj[u.index][j];
                if (!v[i].visited)
                {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (index != -1)
            {
                D.push_front(u);
                v[index].visited = true;
                D.push_front(v[index]);
            }
        }
    }
    //D.~deque<vertice>();//release memory

}
```

Test their elapsed time:

```
void compareDFS() {
    auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    dfsRecursive();
    isExplored();
    auto end1 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    dfsDeque();
    isExplored();
    auto end2 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    dfsStack();
    isExplored();
    auto end3 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_time1 = end1 - start;
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_time2 = end2 - end1;
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_time3 = end3 - end2;
    cout << "dfs recursive takes " << elapsed_time1.count() * 1000 << " ms" << endl;
    cout << "dfs deque takes " << elapsed_time2.count() * 1000 << " ms" << endl;
    cout << "dfs stack takes " << elapsed_time3.count() * 1000 << " ms" << endl;
}
```

I expected these algorithms to run with similar performance, and the deque one>stack>recursive. However, the result shows that:

```
Directed graph generated:
n=50000 m=50000
dfs recursive takes 7.3117 ms
dfs deque takes 87.9806 ms
dfs stack takes 100.113 ms

C:\Users\123\source\repos\DFS_Stack\Debug\DFS_Stack.exe (process 10312) exited with code 0.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

The recursive one is always 10 times faster than the others. Why is that?
The whole code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stack>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <deque>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
using std::vector;
using std::pair;
using std::stack;//neccessary
using std::queue;
struct vertice {
    size_t index = 0;
    bool visited = false;
};
vertice* v;//record the status
vector<vector<int> > adj;//record the neighbours
//void printV(vertice v) {
//  size_t i = v.index;
//  size_t n = adj[i].size();
//  if (n == 0) {
//      puts("");
//      return;
//  }
//  else {
//      for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++) {
//          cout << adj[i][j] << " ";
//      }
//      puts("");
//  }
//}
bool equal(vector<int>& temp, size_t x) {
    //if one veritce adjecancy list temp owns the same element x, this function will return true
    size_t n = temp.size();
    bool equal = false;
    if (n == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        for (size_t c = 0; c < n; c++)
        {
            if (c >= n || c < 0) {
                cout << "vetcor out of range" << endl;
                break;
            }
            if (temp[c] == (int)x)
            {
                equal = true;
                return equal;
            }

        }
        return equal;
    }
}
size_t Num_of_edges(vector<vector<int>>& adj) {
    size_t m = 0;
    size_t n = adj.size();
    //in the adjacancy list, the number of edges is the sum of the edges that each vertice owns
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        m += adj[i].size();
    }


    return m;
}
void Print_adj_list() {
    int n = adj.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int m = adj[i].size();
        cout << i << ": ";
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) { 
            cout << adj[i][j] << " ,"; 
            if (j == m - 1) { break; }
        }
        cout << endl;

    }

}
void Print_adj_matrix() {
    int n = adj.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {//outer loop, print i rows
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {//inner loop, print dots
            if (equal(adj[i], j)) //which means it has the element j
            {
                cout << "1" << " ";
            }
            else
                cout << "0" << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;

    }
}
size_t random(int r, int b) {
    size_t random;
    random = (rand() % (b - r + 1)) + r;//represents [r,b]

//  cout << random << endl;
    return random;
}
bool isExplored() {
    size_t n = adj.size();
    bool eFlag = true;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (!v[i].visited) {
            eFlag = false;
            cout << "Traversal incomplete" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    return eFlag;
}
//check if the vector temp has the same element as x

void generateD(size_t n, size_t m)
{

    cout << "Directed graph generated:" << endl;
    cout << "n=" << n << " m=" << m << endl;
    adj = vector<vector<int> >(n, vector<int>());
    v = new vertice[n];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        v[i].index = i;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++)//push m lines in template vector
    {
        size_t j, k;
        j = random(1, n); //[1,n]
        while (true) {
            if (adj[j - 1].size() == n - 1)
            {
                j = random(1, n);
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        k = random(1, n);
        while (true) {
            if (j == k) {
                k = random(1, n);

            }
            else break;
        }
        if (!equal(adj[j - 1], k - 1))  // if elements are not repeatd or are empty, return false, push element to the back
        {
            adj[j - 1].push_back(k - 1);
        }
        else {
            //make sure there are exactly m edges in the graph, in case the vector has the same elements.
            while (true)
            {
                k = random(1, n);
                if (!equal(adj[j - 1], k - 1) && k != j)//
                {
                    adj[j - 1].push_back(k - 1);
                    break;
                }
            };

        }
    }
    //if (n < 25) {
    //  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    // {
    //  cout << i << ": ";
    //  printV(v[i]);

    // }
    //}

}
void generateU(size_t n, size_t m) {
    cout << "Undirected graph generated:" << endl;
    cout << "n=" << n << " m=" << m << endl;
    adj = vector<vector<int> >(n, vector<int>());
    v = new vertice[n];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        v[i].index = i;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++)//push m lines in template vector
    {
        size_t j, k;
        j = random(1, n); //[1,n]
        //for the smaller example, in case all edges are on the same vertice
        while (true)
        {
            if (adj[j - 1].size() == n - 1)
            {
                j = random(1, n);
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        k = random(1, n);
        while (true) {
            if (j == k) {
                k = random(1, n);

            }
            else break;
        }
        if (!equal(adj[j - 1], k - 1) && !equal(adj[k - 1], j - 1))  // if elements are not repeatd or are empty, return false, push element to the back
        {
            adj[j - 1].push_back(k - 1);
            adj[k - 1].push_back(j - 1);
        }
        else {
            //make sure there are exactly m edges in the graph, in case the vector has the same elements.
            while (true)
            {
                k = random(1, n);
                if (!equal(adj[j - 1], k - 1) && !equal(adj[k - 1], j - 1) && k != j)
                {
                    adj[j - 1].push_back(k - 1);
                    adj[k - 1].push_back(j - 1);
                    break;
                }
            };

        }
    }
    //if (n < 25) {
    //  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    //  {
    //      cout << i << ": ";
    //      printV(v[i]);

    //  }
    //}

}
void generateBi(size_t n, size_t m) {
    cout << "bipartite graph generated" << endl;
    cout << "n=" << n << " m=" << m << endl;
    //distribute n1 vertices for the first block and m1 edges towards the other block
    size_t n1 = random(1, n);
    size_t m1 = random(1, m);
    adj = vector<vector<int> >(n, vector<int>());
    v = new vertice[n];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        v[i].index = i;
    }
    //assign edges from the first block
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m1; i++)//push m1 lines in template vector
    {
        size_t j, k;
        j = random(1, n1); //[1,n1]
        k = random(n1 + 1, n);//[n1+1,n]
        if (!equal(adj[j - 1], k - 1))  // if elements are not repeatd or are empty, return false, push element to the back
        {
            adj[j - 1].push_back(k - 1);
        }
        else {
            //make sure there are exactly m edges in the graph, in case the vector has the same elements.
            while (true)
            {
                k = random(n1 + 1, n);
                if (!equal(adj[j - 1], k - 1))
                {
                    adj[j - 1].push_back(k - 1);
                    break;
                }
            }


        }
    }
    //and the second block
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m - m1; i++)//push m1 lines in template vector
    {
        size_t j, k;
        j = random(1, n1); //[1,n1]
        k = random(n1 + 1, n);//[n1+1,n]
        if (!equal(adj[k - 1], j - 1))  // if elements are not repeatd or are empty, return false, push element to the back
        {
            adj[k - 1].push_back(j - 1);
        }
        else {
            //make sure there are exactly m edges in the graph, in case the vector has the same elements.
            while (true)
            {
                j = random(1, n1);
                if (!equal(adj[k - 1], j - 1))
                {
                    adj[k - 1].push_back(j - 1);
                    break;
                }
            }


        }
    }
}

//generating dense graph simply means build edges between all the nodes

void generateDense(size_t n) 
{
    cout << "Dense graph generated" << endl;
    cout << "n=" << n << " m=" << pow(n,2)<< endl;
    adj = vector<vector<int> >(n, vector<int>());
    v = new vertice[n];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        v[i].index = i;
    }
    for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        for (size_t l = 0; l <n;l++) {
            adj[j].push_back(l);
        }
        
    }
}

void userInterface()
{
    size_t a;
    size_t n = 0, m = 0;
    cout << "Welcome to algorithms test, please select the type of the graph:" << "\n 1.small 2.large\n" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    switch (a)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "You selected small.\n" << endl;
        n = random(5, 20);
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "You selected small.\n" << endl;
        n = random(1000, 100000);
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Input illegal.\n" << endl;
        break;
    }
    cout << " 1.sparse 2.dense\n" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    switch (a)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "You selected sparse.\n" << endl;
        m = n + 2;
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "You selected dense.\n" << endl;
        m = (size_t)(pow(n, 2) - n - 2) / 2;//undirected
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Input illegal.\n" << endl;
        break;
    }

    cout << " 1.directed 2.undirected\n" << endl;
    size_t b;
    cin >> b;
    switch (b) {
    case 1:

        cout << "You selected directed.\n" << endl;
        generateD(n, m);

        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "You selected undirected.\n" << endl;
        generateU(n, m);
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Input illegal.\n" << endl;
        break;

    }
    cout << "Print the graph?(Recommended when small graph is selected)" << "\n 1.Yes 2.No\n" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    switch (a)
    {
    case 1:
        //for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        //{
        //  cout << i << ": ";
        //  printV(v[i]);

        //}
        break;
    case 2:
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Input illegal.\n" << endl;
        break;
    }

};



void explore(int i)
{
    if (!v[i].visited)
    {
        v[i].visited = true;
    
        int n = adj[i].size();
        if (!adj[i].empty())
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                int w = adj[i][j];//acutal index in the vector
                explore(w);
            }
        
        }
        else {
        
            return;
        }//if the vertice is sink, return the upper level 
    }


    else {
        return;
    } //if visited, return immediately
}
void dfsRecursive() //the naive implementation of directed dfs
{

    int n = adj.size();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        v[i].visited = false;
    }
    for (int w = 0; w < n; w++) {
        if (!v[w].visited) {
            explore(w);
            
        }
    }

}
void dfsStack() {
    //using naive c++ stl stack
    size_t n = adj.size();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        v[i].visited = false;
    }
    stack<vertice> S;
    for (size_t k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        if (v[k].visited) { continue; }
        else
            v[k].visited = true;//start point v[0]
        S.push(v[k]);
        while (!S.empty())
        {
            vertice u = S.top();
            S.pop();//these two steps represent the operation pop
            size_t m = adj[u.index].size();
            int  index = -1;
            for (size_t j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                size_t i = adj[u.index][j];
                if (!v[i].visited)
                {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (index != -1)
            {
                S.push(u);
                v[index].visited = true;
                S.push(v[index]);
            }
        }
    }


    //S.~stack<vertice>();//release memory
}
void dfsDeque() {
    size_t n = adj.size();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        v[i].visited = false;
    }
    deque<vertice> D;
    for (size_t k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        if (v[k].visited) { continue; }
        else
            v[k].visited = true;//start point v[0]
        D.push_front(v[k]);
        while (!D.empty())
        {
            vertice u = D.front();
            D.pop_front();
            size_t m = adj[u.index].size();
            int index = -1;
            for (size_t j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                size_t i = adj[u.index][j];
                if (!v[i].visited)
                {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (index != -1)
            {
                D.push_front(u);
                v[index].visited = true;
                D.push_front(v[index]);
            }
        }
    }
    //D.~deque<vertice>();//release memory

}
//void showOrder() {
//  size_t n = adj.size();
//  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
//  {
//      cout << i << ": " << v[i].postOrder << endl;
//
//
//  }
//}
void bfsQueue()
{
    size_t n = adj.size();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        v[i].visited = false;
    }
    queue<vertice> Q;
    for (size_t k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        if (v[k].visited) {
            continue;
        }
        else
            v[k].visited = true;
        Q.push(v[k]);
        while (!Q.empty())
        {
            vertice u = Q.front();
            Q.pop();//these two steps represent the operation dequeue()
            size_t m = adj[u.index].size();
            for (size_t j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                size_t i = adj[u.index][j];
                if (!v[i].visited)
                {
                    v[i].visited = true;
                    Q.push(v[i]);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    //Q.~queue<vertice>();
}
void bfsDeque() {
    size_t n = adj.size();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        v[i].visited = false;
    }
    deque<vertice> D;
    for (size_t k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        if (v[k].visited) { continue; }
        else
            v[k].visited = true;
        D.push_back(v[k]);
        while (!D.empty())
        {
            vertice u = D.front();
            D.pop_front();//these two steps represent the operation dequeue()
            size_t m = adj[u.index].size();
            for (size_t j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                size_t i = adj[u.index][j];
                if (!v[i].visited)
                {
                    v[i].visited = true;
                    D.push_back(v[i]);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    //D.~deque<vertice>();
}
//file format .csv, .txt
void test_dense() {
ofstream exp_data("bipartite_test.txt");// For the convenience of analyzing
    size_t n;

    for (size_t i = 1; i <1000; i++) {
        n = 200 * i;
        generateDense(n);
        // Print_adj_list();
        auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        bfsDeque();
        auto end1 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        dfsDeque();
        auto end2 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        bfsQueue();
        auto end3 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        dfsStack();
        auto end4 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_time1 = end1 - start;
        std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_time2 = end2 - end1;
        std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_time3 = end3 - end2;
        std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_time4 = end4 - end3;
        exp_data << adj.size() << " " << elapsed_time1.count() * 1000 << " " << elapsed_time2.count() * 1000 << " " << elapsed_time3.count() * 1000 << " " << elapsed_time4.count() * 1000 << endl;
    }
    exp_data.close();
}
int Max(size_t a, size_t b, size_t c)
{
    size_t max;
    if (a >= b)
    {
        if (a >= c) {
            max = a;
        }
        else
            max = c;
    }
    else if (b >= c) { max = b; }
    else max = c;
    return max;
}
void compare() {
    auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    bfsDeque();
    auto end1 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    dfsDeque();
    auto end2 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    bfsQueue();
    auto end3 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    dfsStack();
    auto end4 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_time1 = end1 - start;
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_time2 = end2 - end1;
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_time3 = end3 - end2;
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_time4 = end4 - end3;
    cout << "bfs deque takes " <<elapsed_time1.count()*1000 << " ms" << endl;
    cout << "dfs deque takes " << elapsed_time2.count()*1000 << " ms" << endl;
    cout << "bfs queue takes " << elapsed_time3.count() * 1000 << " ms" << endl;
    cout << "dfs stack takes " << elapsed_time4.count() * 1000 << " ms" << endl;
}
void compareDFS() {
    auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    dfsRecursive();
    auto end1 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    dfsDeque();
    auto end2 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    dfsStack();
    auto end3 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_time1 = end1 - start;
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_time2 = end2 - end1;
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_time3 = end3 - end2;
    cout << "dfs recursive takes " << elapsed_time1.count() * 1000 << " ms" << endl;
    cout << "dfs deque takes " << elapsed_time2.count() * 1000 << " ms" << endl;
    cout << "dfs stack takes " << elapsed_time3.count() * 1000 << " ms" << endl;
}
void compareBFS() {
    clock_t t1, t2, t3;
    t1 = clock();//get current time
    bfsQueue();
    t2 = clock();
    double dif1, dif2;
    dif1 = difftime(t2, t1);
    bfsDeque();
    t3 = clock();
    dif2 = difftime(t3, t2);
    cout << "Naive queue takes " << dif1 << " ms" << endl;
    cout << "Deque takes " << dif2 << " ms" << endl;
}
void Input_data(const string& filename) {
    std::fstream in(filename.c_str());
    cout << "reading file:" << filename << endl;
    string s;
    size_t n = 0, m = 0;
    string data1, data2;
    while (true)
    {
        std::getline(in, s);
        istringstream is(s);
        is >> data1 >> data2;
        int d1 = stoi(data1);
        int d2 = stoi(data2);
        n = Max(n, d2, d1);
        m += 1;
        if (in.eof()) { break; }
    }
    //this block will count the number of lines and calculate the maximun number appeared in the file, which are the parameters n, m(vertice, edge)
    in.clear();
    in.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    n += 1;
    m -= 1;
    v = new vertice[n];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        v[i].index = i;
    }
    adj = vector<vector<int> >(n, vector<int>());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        int x, y;
        std::getline(in, s);
        istringstream is(s);
        is >> data1 >> data2;
        x = stoi(data1);
        y = stoi(data2);
        adj[x].push_back(y);
    }
    in.close();
    //this block will assign data into the vertice template in terms of the adjancancy list
}


void Output_data() {
    ofstream data("out.txt");
    size_t n = adj.size();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        size_t m = adj[i].size();
        for (size_t j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            data << i << " " << adj[i][j] << "\n";
        }

    }
    data.close();
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    //Input_data("out.txt");

    srand((int)time(NULL));  // generate random seeds, use and only use once, ensure that every execuation is random
    generateD(10000,10000); //size_t range 18446744073709551615(2^64-1)
    //Print_adj_matrix();
    //Print_adj_list();
        //dfsStack();   
    compareDFS();
    //
    //isExplored();
    //Output_data();
    //test_dense();
    delete[] v; 
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas? Besides, I also want to know why is the deque slightly faster than stack for the searching?

Comment: `C:\Users\123\source\repos\DFS_Stack\Debug\DFS_Stack.exe` suggests you're building in Debug mode. Does switching to Release mode change anything? Performance benchmarks in debug mode or with optimizations off often don't tell you very much.

Comment: @Nathan Pierson Thanks a lot, it did change. 
dfs recursive takes 0.9887 ms\
dfs deque takes 1.5224 ms\
dfs stack takes 1.5397 ms\

But the recursive one is still faster than the others. Any algorithmic suggestions?

Comment: Commenting:  I don't think the concern should be efficiency, but the usage of stack space or the maximum depth of the recursion.

Comment: How large is `vertice`? The recursive algorithm works with integer indices, while stack-based one copies `vertice` structures around. Why do you use `stack<vertice>` and not `stack<int>`?

Comment: The stack-based algorighm loops over `adj[u.index]` multiple times, each time adding only  one vertex to the stack, plus returning the just-popped vertex right back to the stack. That doesn't make any sense - you are walking the same set of edges over and over. When you visit `u`, add **all** the vertices reachable from it to the stack.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you. I have tested what you said and you are right about everything. As for the algorithm, I thought I can have an algorithm where the stack size won't exceed the number of edges m to improve the efficiency. Looks I am totally wrong.

Comment: However, the recursive one is still the fastest...`Directed graph generated:\
n=50000 m=50000\
dfs recursive takes 0.9365 ms\
dfs deque takes 1.1329 ms\
dfs stack takes 1.1371 ms\
dfs stack takes 1.6649 ms\
dfs B takes 1.4017 ms
dfs A takes 1.1616 ms\

C:\Users\123\source\repos\DFS_Stack\Release\DFS_Stack.exe (process 6044) exited with code 0.
Press any key to close this window . . .`